# Datatables spins and loads the entire data set before pagination applies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

[FiddleHere](http://jsfiddle.net/osf9y827/1/)

I have a table that loads a lot of data (up to 1 million rows and 4-6 columns), the data isn't coming from a database, it's coming from an API response so I can't break the query out.

My issue is that depending on the response size (the larger, the longer it takes), datatables does not kick in until the entire table is printed. It happens in jsfiddle with 11604 rows, but you can imagine how much worse it gets when an entire web app is wrapped around this and more data is returned (say 100,000 lines).

What's the best way to handle this? I haven't ever delt with displaying data this large.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableStuff').dataTable();
} );
```

HTML Output: way too long to post here

PHP:

```
//$response = curl response
echo "<table class='display' id='tableStuff'>";
echo "<thead><th>Test 1</th><th>Test 2</th><th>Test 3</th><th>Test 4</th></thead>";
foreach($response as $test){
  echo "<tr><td>". $test['test1'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test2'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test3'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test4'] ."</td><tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have several problems with big datasets:

- **network timeouts** (while retrieving the result, while pushing it to the client, etc)
- **memory footprint** (in your PHP application, in the client's browser, etc)

## On the client side

As soon as you have several thousands of rows you must use **ajax features** of the datatable library to load the data. This way you will load parts of the data, and keep the size of your response small enough to be fast (and rendered fast).

You may need to free some browser memory by unloading previous data segments while adding new ones. You have a part of this behavior described in [the pipeline example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html), where a cache of the data is stored on the client side. By managing such data store on the client side you can try to ensure the size of this data is never too high.

That mean also that a lot of default **features are not available** anymore when using [Server Side processing](http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side). I.e. you cannot use the javascript search, all the filtering stuff has to be done on the serverside also (you do not have the whole dataset on the browser, that would not fit in most browser memory).

## On the server (B-to-B) side

As stated by @Luke H you will have to store the resultset on a database. You cannot retrieve it for each client request.

This will lead to one new problem:

- you will have to **refresh** this data, you have to decide for how long you can use the retrieved data.

But you also have two other problems:

- when requesting in HTTP the data server which does not paginate this data, you may get network timeouts
- when receiving this data on a PHP program you will have memory problems

To limit the memory footprint of the received data you may need to run PHP in **cli** mode (via a cron for example), where the default `php.ini` are usually allowing bigger `memory_limit` settings. Running PHP from Apache you should not allow a `memory_limit=1Go`, bad idea.

You could also try to reduce the memory usage by managing file-based memory, components like [Zend_memory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.memory.memory-manager.html) could be used for that.

But first you'll have to ensure that curl can retrieve the result without crashing.

## Well...

It's very strange that the *API server* does not manage pagination. Having an HTTP API returning millions of rows is an issue in the API. If you have some control over this API then fix it (and make it a server-side datatable API if you can). If you do not have any control on this APi then you'll have to find the right way to extract data in small subsets, store it locally (be careful you need a big database), build a server-side datatable API around it, refresh the data in an asynchronous way (crons), re-think the client side to work in ajax mode.

This is why real applications are always harder to build than demos.

Comment: This is great, basically similar ideas that I had, but beautifully expressed with real detail. I must start answering questions like this.

Comment: I don't have control over the API response, it's basically a `select * from date x to date x` response. Which some times will have millions of lines, sometimes will have 5 depending on what account is running it. I can not store anything in a database for legal reasons. Could the above be done with session variables?

Comment: using session is technically a local storage (on file by default, but can be on database), so that's the same. Now, using a server-side communication implies technically a local storage (at least in-memory), so you should investigate this 'legal' restriction which is obviously just a technical nightmare.

Comment: I figured out the API allows pagination, so the pagination route will work for me. Just need to figure out server side processing with datatables. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using PHP, then I would definitely recommend segmenting this data if possible and ideally making the queries based on some message queue or cron, rather than when a page is loaded.  This is a **LOT** of data to be loading for a webpage!

You could make the curl request, and cache the response in a database, then paginate based on URL parameters and load sections via AJAX.

See http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side

**Pseudocode**:

```
<?php // The code that interacts with dataTables
// fetch from database, using pagination
$response = get_page_data($start, $count);

echo "<table class='display' id='tableStuff'>";
echo "<thead><th>Test 1</th><th>Test 2</th><th>Test 3</th><th>Test 4</th></thead>";
foreach($response as $test){
    echo "<tr><td>". $test['test1'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test2'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test3'] ."</td><td>" .$test['test4'] ."</td><tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

In any case, I think you're going to cause the user some frustration if they have to wait for 100,000 table rows to load and render, if their browser doesn't simply crash.

Comment: It was simply crashing in my scenario which is how I noticed it. I don't have time to test this today, I'll test it tomorrow and get back to you on if it works in my scenario.